# How to create folders and shift files into each of these folders in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have 100 images in a folder. I want to create folders with names like

PC0001,PC0002.....PC0100 and transfer one image into each of these folders.

Can I do that using VBA in Excel

Comment: How does your approach look like? [so] is not a coding service...

Comment: But to answer your question, yes, you can do it with VBA in Excel.

Comment: Look for code that will enumerate the files in the folder into a collection, you can then step through each item in the collection.  Use a counter which will add 1 each time a new file is being looked at - convert this to text so that it retains leading zeros.  Add some more code that will strip the file name from the full path - look for the last `/` in the path string using `INSTRREV`. Build a directory tree for each file (maybe by calling the same function recursively) including your text counter and save the file in there.

Answer (score 0):

### Achievable in VBA.

Use these functions in your attempt at this exercise:

- [Copy file in VBA](http://analystcave.com/vba-reference-functions/vba-file-functions/vba-filecopy-function/)
- [Create directory in VBA](http://Create%20folder%20in%20VBA)
- [Iterate all files (images) in directory](http://analystcave.com/vba-reference-functions/vba-file-functions/vba-dir-function/)
- [Delete old file (image) in VBA](http://analystcave.com/vba-reference-functions/vba-file-functions/vba-kill-function/)

**Post your code on StackOverflow and we will be sure to help.**